# Don't print list items starting with particular letter

Tags: python

```
names = ["Adam", "Maria", "Kevin", "Madison", "John", "Bailey"]
```

I want all the items in this string to print except the names that begin with the letter M. How do I do that. I just started an online course and I am trying to figure this part out. I have re-watched some of the videos and seem to miss the information that will get everything to print that does not start with M.

Comment: Try to create a string and see how you can index to print only certain letter of the string. Once you have worked that out then you can just use a loop.

Comment: `[x for x in names if not x.startswith("M")]`

Comment: We don't do you homework.  Given a string, how do you get its first character?  How do you check if that first character is a M?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for name in names:
    if not name.startswith('M'):
        print(name)
```

If you want to check for lowercase `m` as well, you can do `if not name.lower().startswith('m'):` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I will see how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ["Adam", "Maria", "Kevin", "Madison", "John", "Bailey"]
for name in names:
  if name[0] == 'M':
    continue
  print(name)
```

Comment: Friendly hint: This can be simplified (both code-wise and interpretation) by using the `!=` operator; thus removing the `continue` and printing when validated to True.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions on this. I will check on this.